# Qt4: ActionX added to multiple widgets. How to determine which widget triggered the action in the on_actionX_triggered() slot

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have an `actionX` defined in my `MainWindow` and I have added this action to the context menu of a few `treewidgets`.

In the `MainWindow::on_actionX_triggered()` slot, how can I figure out which treewidget triggered the action?

I've tried the following with not much luck:

```
    void MainWindow::on_actionX_triggered()
    {
       qDebug()<<sender();  //outputs: QAction(0xe957dd8) 
       qDebug()<<sender()->parent(); //outputs: MainWindow(0x28fdfc, name = "MainWindow")
       qDebug()<<this->parent(); //outputs: QObject(0x0)  
    }
```

**(Jan 27 2013) EDIT :** I'm sorry, but I felt compelled to **BUMP** this question to see if anyone can provide a solution... Thanks.

Comment: Anyone, please? Any hints on this issue?

Comment: 25 days and no answers at all? Is that question so hard??? :(

Comment: Note that when commenting on your own question, you're only talking to yourself. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions for information on the best way to draw attention to your question. I've edited your question to be a little more clear by removing some of the other stuff - perhaps that will help.